# MySQL How to select rows 2 duplicate column values in ascending order

Tags: mysql

I have a table as such:

```
id1  |  id2  |  id3
-------------------
 1      'B'       1
 1      'B'       2
 1      'C'       1
 1      'C'       2
 2      'A'       1
 2      'A'       2
```

From this table I want to retrieve rows that contain the lowest combination of `id1` and then `id2`. So the first query will return the first two rows: lowest `id1` is 1 and out of those, lowest `id2` is 'B'. Then if I delete them then the second query will return rows three and four.

I have the following query:

```
select * 
from table_1 
where id2 = (
    select min(id2) 
    from table_1 
    where id1 = (
        select min(id1) 
        from table_1
    )
)
```

Is that the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `RANK` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id1, id2) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id1, id2, id3
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

This assumes that you are using MySQL 8+.  If not, there are other ways to handle your query, but if you have a long term need for such queries then consider upgrading.

If you are on MySQL 5.7 or earlier, then use this version:

```
SELECT id1, id2, id3
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    id1 = (SELECT MIN(id1) FROM yourTable) AND
    id2 = (SELECT MIN(id2) FROM yourTable
           WHERE id1 = (SELECT MIN(id1) FROM yourTable));
```

### Demo

Comment: I'm using a cloud solution and they only have MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @Dula I gave you an option which should work on MySQL 5.7 or earlier.